# Sumar los valores en un array de objetos dependiendo del valor fecha de cada objeto javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un array con esta forma:

```
[{start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 3600} 
,{start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1500, time: 6400},
{start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 1300}]
```

quiero sumar los valores distance y time agrupandolos por el mes que indique el valor start_date por ejemplo si dos start_dates tienen el mismo mes 2022-12-01 y 2022-12-08 como puedo sumar los valores de distance y time de esos dos meses

Answer (score 0):

El tema de agrupar valores de arrays de objetos ya ha sido respondido varias veces, en mi opinión es mas sencillo (aunque poco intuitivo) utilizar `.reduce`  en donde en el acumulador se implemente un array anidado de manera de que el acumulador quede de la forma [[criterio],[resultado]], en este caso el criterio es el mes de una fecha (en forma de string), que en mi opinión debería ser pasado a tipo `Date`.

```js
const arr =  [{start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 100, time: 100}, 
              {start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 10, time: 10},
              {start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 100, time: 100},
              {start_date: "2022-02-08T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 10, time: 10}];

const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => {

  let mes = new Date(c.start_date).getMonth() + 1;

  let idx = p[0].indexOf(mes);

  if (idx < 0) {

    p[0].push(mes);
    p[1].push({
      mes: mes,
      distance: c.distance,
      time: c.time
    });

  } else {

    p[1][idx].distance += c.distance;
    p[1][idx].time += c.time;

  }

  return p;

}, [
  [],
  []
]);

console.log(res[1]);
```